# Eloquent relationship select returns empty array

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So I have question with eloquent. I fetch data like this:

```
$model::query()
        ->with([
           'codes',
           'codes.status',
           'codes.company',
           'codes.type',
           'codes.item.serials',
         ])->get();
```

This returns all columns, but as soon as I provide select method to select certain columns my `$model` returns empty `array`

```
$model::query()
        ->with([
           'codes' => function ($query) {
              $query->select('code');
           },
           'codes.status',
           'codes.company',
           'codes.type',
           'codes.item.serials',
         ])->get();
```

Why is this happening and how to fix this?

Comment: When you use `->select()` in a `with()` function, you need to make sure you select the columns you want and the foreign key, otherwise, no join can be done. Something like `select(['id', 'model_id', 'code'])` (or similar; I can only guess due to `$model` being ambiguous)

Comment: Yea, didn't knew that. Providing foreign key solved it.

Comment: No worries! If you haven't seen it before, it can be a little difficult to debug due to the lack of SQL logging in default Laravel installs. Glad you got it working though 